# Rails_Admin Sign out not Redirecting (Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, devise, rails-admin

We are using Devise, Rails_Admin and Simple_Token_Authentication (for API) in our application.

Everything is working fine except for sign out. When we click on Sign out, following request is made and the user gets signed out.

> Started DELETE "/admins/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-12 18:50:44
>   +0530 Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"authenticity_token"=>"rtSRPzpRN7cWEk8wV8q6VDAUB575ZV46JeFFlMFVOQc="}
>   Admin Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "admins".* FROM "admins"  WHERE
>   "admins"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "admins"."id" ASC LIMIT 1    (0.1ms) 
>   begin transaction    (0.1ms)  commit transaction Completed 204 No
>   Content in 700ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

The problem is that the page does not redirect after sign out.

On pressing the sign out button again, here is the request:

> Started DELETE "/admins/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-12 19:01:59
>   +0530 Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"authenticity_token"=>"dHuxA5hRosyquhlsRmchK3vW9bQOCM/YXYXUNMxTufc="}
>   Filter chain halted as :verify_signed_out_user rendered or redirected
>   Completed 204 No Content in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Here is the application controller (app/controllers/application_controller.rb):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery

  skip_before_filter :verify_signed_out_user

  respond_to :html, :json

  protected

  # Overwriting the sign_out redirect path method   
  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)        
   request.referrer   
  end 
end
```

Here is the devise related code in app/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb

```
config.authenticate_with do   
  warden.authenticate! scope: :admin   
end
config.current_user_method(&:current_admin)
```

Please suggest. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't know if this will work or not but can you try making a custom `SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController` inheriting devise controller and adding this in routes file and adding `skip_before_filter :verify_signed_out_user, only: :destroy` there.

Comment: Hi Deep. Already tried that.. didn't work.

Comment: There is one more method written to be overided in this link `Devise::Controllers::Helpers#stored_location_for` https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-redirect-path-after-destroying-a-session-i.e.-signing-out may be this help you

Comment: Try changing `request.referrer` in `after_sign_out_path` to `root_path`.

Comment: Hi Pavan, it does not work

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)`.

`request.referrer` redirects to the ***current page***.

Change the `after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)` accordingly. If you want to ***redirect*** to `root_path`, then below would work.

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)        
   root_path   
end
```